# Changing text into an input and then back again on deselection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button, when i click it, i transform its sibling into an input containing the text that it once held.

This works fine.

However, upon deselection of the input, I require it to go back to being text again, but the issue is, the const variable is being overwritten somehow?

Anyway, here is my current HTML and JS:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "table.table-striped > tbody > tr > td > a.copy-btn", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const $this = $(this),
      text = $this.parent().parent().find("td.link").text();

    $this.parent().parent().find("td.link").html(`<input type="text" class="form-control" value="${text}">`);

    $this.parent().parent().find("td.link input").select();

    if ($this.parent().parent().find("td.link input").blur()) {
      $this.parent().parent().find("td.link").html(text);
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="title">link name</th>
      <th class="title">Platform</th>
      <th class="title">Link</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="body-text" scope="row">1</th>
      <td class="body-text">Mark</td>
      <td class="body-text link">Otto</td>
      <td class="body-text"><a href="#" class="copy-btn">Copy</a>
      </td>
      <td class="body-text"><a href="#" class="more-btn">More</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="body-text" scope="row">1</th>
      <td class="body-text">Otto</td>
      <td class="body-text link">Mark</td>
      <td class="body-text"><a href="#" class="copy-btn">Copy</a>
      </td>
      <td class="body-text"><a href="#" class="more-btn">More</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You have several syntax errors? For instance `.find("td.link".html(text)` etc.

Comment: Not sure why they are there, in the code I copy pasted to you, there werent there, perhaps it was the tidy functionality of the SO editor? look at the code again, will re-enter the code.

Comment: you get the gist though, of that I am sure, any ideas how to achieve what i am aiming for? tried detecting blur, !focus, etc but not doing as expected, as I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `$this.parent().parent().find("td.link input").blur()` will always return true.
It fires the `blur` event, and returns the jQuery collection.

If you wanted to check if the element was focused, the easiest would be just

```
$this.parent().parent().find("td.link input").get(0) === document.activeElement
```

However, that's not really what you want, you want an event handler instead, and you can add that during the creation of the element like this *(with cleaned up code and cached elements etc)*

```js
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "table.table-striped > tbody > tr > td > a.copy-btn", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this  = $(this),
            parent = $this.parent().parent(),
            link   = parent.find("td.link"),
            text   = link.text(),
            input  = $('<input />', {
                'class' : 'form-control',
                value   : text,
                type    : 'text',
                on      : {
                    blur : function() {
                     $(this).parent().html(text);
                    }
                }
            });

        link.html(input);
        input.select().focus();

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="title">link name</th>
            <th class="title">Platform</th>
            <th class="title">Link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="body-text" scope="row">1</th>
            <td class="body-text">Mark</td>
            <td class="body-text link">Otto</td>
            <td class="body-text"><a href="#" class="copy-btn">Copy</a>
            </td>
            <td class="body-text"><a href="#" class="more-btn">More</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="body-text" scope="row">1</th>
            <td class="body-text">Otto</td>
            <td class="body-text link">Mark</td>
            <td class="body-text"><a href="#" class="copy-btn">Copy</a>
            </td>
            <td class="body-text"><a href="#" class="more-btn">More</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ($this.parent().parent().find("td.link input").blur()) {
      $this.parent().parent().find("td.link").html(text);
}
```

to

```
var $input = $this.parent().parent().find("td.link input");
$input.off("blur")
$input.on("blur", function () {
     $this.parent().parent().find("td.link").html(text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you had in mind?

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "table.table-striped > tbody > tr > td > a.copy-btn", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const $this = $(this),
              text = $this.parent().parent().find("td.link").text();

        $this.parent().parent().find("td.link").html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + $.trim(text) + '">');

        $this.parent().parent().find("td.link input").select();
            $($this).closest('tr').find('.form-control').on('blur', function () {
            var xThis = this;
            var finText = $(xThis).val();
            $(xThis).closest('td').html(finText);
            $(xThis).off('blur');
        });

        return false;
    });
})();
```

See my jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/fictus/mmwc06gm/